# How can I user isnumeric and not isnumeric functions together?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a stock program over Excel integrated with Barcode reader.
With the following code, I could read numeric barcodes to textbox without any problem.

Barcode code like `101010` or `8693457248273`

```
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
    TextBox2.SetFocus
    TextBox2.SelStart = 1
    TextBox2.SelLength = Len(TextBox2.Text)
    Cancel = True
    Else
End If
```

When I try to read barcodes as `730MT30151`, above code line not works.
But if I delete `Not` expression inside of the above code. It works.
However this time I could not read numeric barcodes.

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
    TextBox2.SetFocus
    TextBox2.SelStart = 1
    TextBox2.SelLength = Len(TextBox2.Text)
    Cancel = True
    Else
End If
```

So I just want to mix both two codes but I could not achieve it.
Does anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you expect from your code? The first code disallows letters and the second one disallows values that are numbers-only values. Remove the code completely and it should accept all values.

Comment: Yeah i tried it and worked before however i could not setfocus cursor to textbox2 after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code basically means cancel (`Cancel = True`) all inputs that contain text (`Not IsNumeric`).

```
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
    TextBox2.SetFocus
    TextBox2.SelStart = 1
    TextBox2.SelLength = Len(TextBox2.Text)
    Cancel = True
Else
End If
```

Actually the code is a limitation to numbers only. So if you now want to allow numbers **and** letters just remove that (limitation) code completely.

If you want to keep the selection and focus stuff just keep this lines:

```
TextBox2.SetFocus
TextBox2.SelStart = 1
TextBox2.SelLength = Len(TextBox2.Text)
```

Comment: It works for both numbers and letters but this time i could not setfocus cursor to textbox2.